# Issues with using glmnet package for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, lasso, ridge-regression, computational-statistics

I am trying to use the `glmnet` MATLAB package to train my elastic net model on some huge data. My features are of size 13200, and I have around 6000 samples of these. I directly tried to use `lassoglm` in MATLAB with these features and corresponding target taking cross validation to just 3 folds and alpha = 0.5. It's already 6 hours and it hasn't finished. I have to do it for several others as well.

Any suggestions what I should do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about just programming ... Better to ask it on stackoverflow and if you want to get an answer ... you need to provide a minimal code to re-produce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert.

In R, I have got ( after 11 hours!!) : Warning message:
from glmnet Fortran code - Convergence for 10th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned.

So you might want to first set maxit very low and then investigate further.

Also I assume your data is in a sparse matrix?

Comment: No it is not sparse

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the matlab interface, but in the R version you can control the maximum number of non-zeros using dfmax. Try to set that to something small and see if it works. Also, alpha=0.5 leads to the elastic-net which will increase the number of non-zero variables in the model, try with a larger alpha.